# ZKOSS - creating new css theme

Tags: css, zk

I am new to Zkoss and i need to create completely new css theme for my pages. In documentation I found that it can be done by overwriting default z-classes. So I created my own classes like `.z-datebox-inp` etc. (according to styleguide) but when I inspect elements on page, they have rules from both classes, Zkoss default(comes from zk.wcs) and my custom class (my css file). Sometimes zkoss default class even overrides mine so I have to add `body` selector before my class name to make it prior to browser. Is there any way to get rid of zkoss default css styles completely or do I have to rewrite every single css rule that comes from default class? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a theme which is entirely new I would recommend that you use a ThemeProvider. You can use it to control which CSS files are included.

For more information please refer to the [following documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Theming%20and%20Styling/Theme%20Providers).

Comment: Yes I found that few minutes ago, first I tried this http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Configuration%20Reference/zk.xml/The%20desktop-config%20Element/The%20disable-theme-uri%20Element and it helped, but I will definetely try implementing my provider. Thanks!